# Testing route in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to Angular6 where I want to test my routing but got an error saying:

> Failed: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

I don't understand how I ended up with that when I have already imported HomeComponent to my **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [
  HomeComponent
]
```

in my **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [
  HomeComponent
]
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes);
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it("should have as title 'ba-dashboard'", async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('ba-dashboard');
  }));

});
```

The error appears when I add .withRoutes(routes) in my **app.component.spec.ts**

Comment: You have to add HomeComponent import into your app.component.spec.ts file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing HomeComponent in test declarations, and as sad above you have missing HomeComponent in app.module declarations

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes);
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent // missing declaration
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it("should have as title 'ba-dashboard'", async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('ba-dashboard');
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing declaration in your app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
       HomeComponent 
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must Add Home Component as declaration in @NgModule

```
 @NgModule({ 
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
     exports: [RouterModule],   
     declarations: [HomeComponent]
 })
```